# Php://input

Tags: php

Привет встретил код

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Этот метод нужен чтобы получить содержимое POST и GET запросов?Чем уже $_POST и $_GEt не устроил?
Зачем вообще нужен этот ужас?

Читая статью трудно въехать для чего нужны эти самые потоки...Ни примеров ни толквого изложения....
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/wrappers.php.php

Comment: file_get_contents читает содержимое файла, вроде как. При чем тут запросы?

Comment: читает еще модержимое потоков...А что это за потоки,реки...мне не понятно.Дебилный раздел PHP

Answer (score 11, accepted):

чем вас мануал не устраивает?

оригинал:

> php://input is a read-only stream

перевод:

> php://input является потоком только
> для чтения

оригинал:

> php://input instead of
> $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not
> depend on special php.ini directives.
> Moreover, for those cases where
> $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated
> by default, it is a potentially less
> memory intensive alternative to
> activating
> always_populate_raw_post_data.

перевод:

> В случае POST-запросов
> предпочтительней использовать
> php://input вместо
> $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA, так как этот
> метод не зависит от специальных
> php.ini директив. Кроме того, в тех
> случаях, где $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA не
> заполняется по умолчанию, это
> потенциально менее затратно для
> памяти, чем активация директивы
> always_populate_raw_post_data.

оригинал:

> php://input is not available with
> enctype="multipart/form-data"

перевод:

> php://input не доступен с типом
> содержимого
> enctype="multipart/form-data"

читать надо внимательней

Comment: Ухты я поставил в php.ini post_max_size=1KB
 и действительно $_POST пустой а file_get_contents('php://input') содержит все данные которые передавали....

Comment: удивительное рядом :-D

Answer (score 36):

К примеру вам нужно отправить json сериализованную строку.
Передавать это нужно через POST, потому что в GET длина этой самой строки ограничена, кажется, 4мя килобайтами.

Что же именно передается POST методом ?

А передается вот что:

```
POST /test/script.php HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Content-Length: xxxx
... и другие заголовки..

paramName1=paramValue1&paramName2=paramValue2...
```

Передавать что-то типа: `abc=<json_string>` не хочется, потому что нужно экранировать еще эту строку.

Поэтому мы просто скармливаем строку скрипту. На сервер прийдет что-то типа такого:

```
POST /test/script.php HTTP/1.1
Host: site.com
Content-Length: xxxx
... и другие заголовки..

{"paramName1": "paramValue2","paramName2": "paramValue2",...}
```

Естественно, сервер не умеет парсить такие запросы, поэтому нам на помощь приходит `file_get_contents('php://input');`

Мы можем получить то, что нам прислали, без изменений, самим распарсить это и быть счастливым :)

Answer (score 2):

Список методов не ограничивается GET и POST. Например в REST спецификации используются еще PUT, DELETE и еще какие-то.  Обрабатываются они соответственно через php://input.

А смысл то простой, мы получаем таким образом сырой запрос, очень полезная штука.