# PHP не получает POST переменные на хостинге

Tags: php, post, request, hosting

Мне нужен был сервер, чтобы сохранять в файл данные из POST запроса.
я создал новый сайт на хостинге, прицепил к нему домен от freenom, в `index.php` написал
`var_dump($_POST)`, послал на него такой запрос через консоль браузера

```js
let response = await fetch('https://color-msg-slv.tk/', {
method: 'POST',
body: {data: 'gg'}
});
let result = await response.text();
console.log(result);
```

Но в массиве`$_POST` ничего не было. Я попробовал разные варианты - `body: JSON.stringify({data: 'gg'})` `formData` - но ничего не помогло. Я обратился в тех.поддержку, там 2 дня решали вопрос, в итоге мне сказали указать заголовок
`'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'` - с ним мне удалось отправить `body: 'gg'`, но всякие объекты - нет.
Я попробовал `headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' + JSON.stringify({data: 'gg'})` - тоже не помогло

```js
let response = await fetch('https://color-msg-slv.tk/', {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    data: '123'
  }),
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
});
console.log(await response.text())
```

```js
let response = await fetch('https://color-msg-slv.tk/', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: (new FormData()).append('data', '123'),
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    } }); console.log(await response.text())
```

При этом через postman POST запрос работает правильно - то есть var_damp выводит то, что я и отправил, а не пустоту

Из-за чего это происходит? У меня есть второй сайт на этом хостинге, и там всё работает нормально.

Comment: Может стоит проверить [официальную документацию](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) и делать соответственно ей? Меньше гаданий и телодвижений.

Comment: Документацией я пользовался, пользуюсь и буду пользоваться) Но решение вопроса я там не нашел.

Comment: используйте `FormData`, php не умеет json в POST из коробки

Comment: Спасибо, но так тоже не работает(

Comment: Смотрите по логам сервера что приходит, либо что есть в [input://](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/262372/php-input)

Comment: Что консоль браузера пишет?

Comment: Ничего не пишет, ошибок нет, всё чисто. В network виден запрос - `{data: 'gg'}

Comment: Проблему я решил, нужно было `FormData` вынести в переменную. Почему-то `(new FormData())` не работает